# comparing an input to two characters, creates odd warning

Tags: c, logic

I am trying to compare an input to two different characters and execute the if condition if either of the conditions are met.

My code so far is:

```
if(i == 'Y'||'y') {
        //code here
}
```

but the GCC compiler spits out the warning:

```
warning: use of logical '||' with constant operand
      [-Wconstant-logical-operand]
```

why is this happening?

Comment: `if(i == 'Y'||'y')` is not valid syntax. You want `if(i == 'Y' || i == 'y')`

Comment: @Tyle Roper, It is valid syntax. It simply doesn't do what the OP desires to do.

Comment: @ikegami Appreciate the correction. Will leave it there for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you meant to say was:

```
  if(i == 'Y'|| i == 'y')
```

The compiler is telling you exactly what you needed to know!

Comment: Oh! I see, the compiler is trying to sort out some gibberish of how on earth you OR two constants against each other. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to repeat the conditional (i.e for a long list of options) you can use:

```
if (strchr("Yy", i) != NULL) {
    ....
}
```

You need to `#include <string.h>`

Comment: What if there is no terminator at the end, so that `i` is not a valid string?

Comment: Why do need a function call to replace simple comparisons? OP did not ask this.

Comment: @WeatherVane, as I said: this is valid if you don't want to repeat again and again the conditional

Comment: As I said, it might be a useful tip but this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @MeikVtune: `strchr` wants an `int` not a string as second parameter